# C# Json parser - take one by one

Tags: c#, json

I have service that will receive some data in 'json', i don't know which data. However I have set of attributes that might be there. 
the Json format is something like this and can't be changed, names could be different:

```
{"Parent1":
     {"Child1":"Value1","Child2":"Value2"},
 "Parent2":
     {"Child1":"Value1","Child2":"Value2"},
 "Parent3":
     {"Child1":
          {"SubChild1":"Value1","SubChild2":"Value2"}}
}
```

I want to enumerate through all items to be able get key:value pairs. 
Please note that hierarchy is important as several objects could have the same key but different parent.
Also please note that I don't know keys, i need to get keys as well as values, so I can't get a POCO object out of this straight away.

So the question basically is: how to get a collection that would implement some iterator through all the properties (with accessor to both key and value) and would support hierarchy.

Comment: Try exploring Json.net , it is useful library for Serializing /De-serializing Json, if you do not object type then also you can iterate it, try exploring JSonArray.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can always deserialize the JSON input into some (untyped) DOM where you can traverse the tree which represents the JSON document. There are a couple of options: the [JavaScriptSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer.aspx) class, which will deserialize that JSON into a `Dictionary<string, object>` (for arrays it would deserialize into an `object[]`). Or you can use a third-party library, such as [JSON.NET](http://json.net), which you can deserialize arbitrary JSON into a JToken/JObject/JArray/JValue tree, and traverse it using the methods from those classes.

Comment: Thanks, that what I'm doing know - with newtonsoft library... however don't really happy because they have one extra level in each level of hierarchy... hard to explain... Thank you

Answer (score 1):

It's not really clear from your question how much knowledge you have about the format of the returned JSON. If you don't know any of the key names, you're probably not going to be able to use a deserializer and get nice C# POCO's out of it.

Your best bet is probably to use the C# [dynamic](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264736.aspx) type. The Facebook C# SDK uses dynamic for this very reason, so they don't have to try and stay up to date with ever changing data. You can read their justifications [here](http://blog.ntotten.com/2010/09/07/dynamic-objects-and-the-facebook-c-sdk/), and maybe it can give some suggestions of how you can model your data similarly.

Comment: I have a quick look at link you have posted here, they are using keys to access properties, when i want other way: to have collection of objects and then retrieving key-value pairs. I could get dynamic and convert it to Dictionary, however i hope there is more clean way. Please correct me if i wrong, thank you

Comment: If you don't know anything about the structure of your data, that's probably the best you can do.